# Using Filter function in Google Sheets to filter cels that contain a certain value

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, case-insensitive

I am trying to use the filter function or any related function in order to filter all values that contain that value, but for some reason I am not succeeding yet.

To use an example, in the list below **I would like to filter all values that contain banana**.
Let's assume that this is Column A row  1-6 in the Google Sheet.

```
Banana flavor  
Mandarin  
Banana  
Banana boat  
Banana beach  
Peach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**EDIT**
Following both your comments:
*"Is it also possible to put them vertical without blank cells?"*.
AND
*"it only returns Banana if you enter Banana in my file, not if you enter banana. How can this be fixed?"*

**The fix**
To have the formula **omit blank cells**, **wrap in a query** and in order to make the regex **case insensitive, use `(?i)`**.

```
=QUERY(
   INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A7,"(?i)Banana")=true,A1:A7,)),
      " where Col1<>'' ")
```

[image: regex query case insensitive]

You can even have the value **`Banana` in a cell** like `D1`

In that case one should use

```
=QUERY(
   INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A7,"(?i)"&D1&"")=true,A1:A7,)),
      " where Col1<>'' ")
```

---

**Original answer**

Please try

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:A7,"Banana")=true,A1:A7,))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image: filter using regexmatch]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Is it also possible to put them vertical without blank cells?

Comment: One last question. We actually use this formule to return the value that matches a search query. Now it is case sensitive. So it only returns Banana if you enter Banana in my file, not if you enter banana. 

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Answer updated covering both your comments.

Comment: You are using the regular_expression incorrectly. I have edited the answer to meet your needs. I also created a new sheet with the new formula to use. You can delete it after copying the formula.

Comment: You are truly amazing! Could you maybe explain the working of the formula as well? I am really eager to learn and understand the working of the function as well as rules how to use the expressions.